# Twilio unable to record incoming call conversation (not related to leave a message)

Tags: twilio, call, record

In the incoming call back url

I have the next code:

**Twilio Call id**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['CallSid'])){
    $tw_call_id = $_REQUEST['CallSid'];
}
else {
    $tw_call_id = '';<br />
}<br />

$sid = "Axxxx";
$token = "Txxxx";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$recording = $twilio->calls($tw_call_id)
                    ->recordings
                    ->create([
                                 "recordingStatusCallback" => "https://mycode.php",
                                 "recordingStatusCallbackEvent" => ["completed"],
                                 "recordingChannels" => "dual"
                             ]
                    );
```

After this I have a say() and a dial() , so I want to record the say and the dial , no only the dial call 
I got the error
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Requested resource is not eligible for recording in /var/www/html/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Version.php

What I am looking for is to record the complete conversation from incoming call